# Arcpy Create Polygon Geometry or Shapefile/FeatureLayer from WKT

Tags: arcpy, polygon, geometry, well-known-text, iterator

I have a polygon feature class that i am looping through row by row. I want to take each row/record and create it into its own Polygon Geometry or Shapefile/FeatureLayer using WKT

**PolygonGeometry Attempt:**

```
summary = 'fc'
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(summary, ["SHAPE@"]):
    wellknown = row[0].WKT
    arcpy.Polygon(wellknown)
```

I have tried

```
arcpy.Polygon(*[wellknown])
```

also

```
arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*wellknown)]))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rzagha\Desktop\RTK\python\FreighMunicipality.py", line 121, in <module>
    hm = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*wkt)]))
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 6 arguments (36467 given)
```

whats the correct syntax to create a polygon geometry from WKT and is there an easier way to create a featurelayer or shapefile from current row/record within the for loop like

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(row[0], "zone")
```

or

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(row[0].wkt, "zone")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the current row's OID to the where clause of `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management`.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(summary, ['OID@', 'name']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        layerName = 'layer_{}'.format(name)
        print(layerName)
        where_clause = '"OBJECTID" = {}'.format(row[0])
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (summary, layerName, where_clause)
```

Comment: I am still curious though how one would create a Polygon from WKT using arcpy

Comment: You could construct the geometry object with the [`.fromWKT`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/fromwkt.htm) method and pass that to the `SHAPE@` field with an InsertCursor as illustrated in Brian's response.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to make shapefiles you could do something like this:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fc = r'C:\temp\someShapefile.shp'

dataCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@', 'someField'])

for row in dataCursor:
    sr = row[0].spatialReference
    newFC = r'C:\temp\{0}.shp'.format(row[1])
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(newFC), os.path.basename(newFC), 'POLYGON', spatial_reference=sr)
    insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newFC, ['SHAPE@'])
    insertCursor.insertRow([row[0]])
    del insertCursor

del dataCursor
```

This loops through your file and creates a new shapefile for every record using a field value as the new shapefile's name using [insertCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm).  Using WKT isn't necessary unless you needed to for some reason.

Comment: I knew I could do this, but i was wondering if there was a quicker easier way. Like put my row into a make feature layer. using WKT is something I was just curious about using to make a Polygon.